Generating a rational equation with nice solutions
I'm attempting to write a CheckIt bank for precalculus, and one of our outcomes is to ask students to solve rational equations, e.g.
$$\dfrac{x+6}{x+2} - 1 = \dfrac{x+5}{x+7}$$
This one happens to solve to $(x+6)(x-3)=0$, which has nice solutions $x=-6,3$. This example was created manually through trial and error.
My question is: how can I generate randomized versions of similar equations, resulting in an equation $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ for $a,b$ integers, for two possible scenarios:

The term $(x-a)$ appears in a denominator (yielding one solution).
Neither term $(x-a)$ nor $(x-b)$ appears in a denominator (yielding two solutions).


For posterity, I used an alternate format for case 1, to get something with 1 solution:
$$c + \dfrac{d}{x-a} + \dfrac{e}{(x-a)(x-b)} = 0$$
simplifies to
$$(x-a)(cx+f)=0$$
provided $d = f + bc$ and $e = bd-af-abc$. Then only $x=\frac{f}{c}$ is a valid solution.

The equation $$\frac{x+c}{x+d} + e = \frac{x+f}{x+g}$$ has solutions $x=a$ and $x=b$ if
$$ \eqalign{c &= -\frac{a b e +a d e +b d e +d^{2} e -d^{2}+d g}{d -g}\cr f &= 
-\frac{a b e +a e g +b e g +e \,g^{2}-d g +g^{2}}{d -g}}$$
with $d \ne g$.
If you want to ensure that $c$ and $f$ are integers, take $d = g \pm 1$.

It may-or-may-not be helpful to write $$c=d+e,\frac{(a+d)(b+d)}{g-d}\qquad
f=g+e,\frac{(a+g)(b+g)}{g-d}$$

Nice! An additional edge case: if it turns out $c=d$ or $f=g$, then a solution is lost (either $a=-c$ or $b=-f$).

To avoid this, ensure $a+d,a+g,b+d,b+g$ are all nonzero.
